# Which rule/guideline does this break (adding attributes to orm instance)

Tags: django, django-orm, terminology

I came across this code:

```
class MyModel(model.Model):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self._log_data = dict()
        super(MyModel, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def send_data(self, obj):
        self._log_data['foo'] = obj.foo
        ...
```

I just have the feeling that adding `._log_data` to an orm instance is wrong.

Up to now I just have this feeling that this implementation is not obvious and I am missing the matching term.

According to which rule/guideline is this not clean/good code?

Comment: Why do you think it breaks anything? Django models are just Python classes, it's perfectly fine to add attributes to them.

Comment: For me it looks strange. I like it simple: Input-Processing-Output. `_log_data` looks like a return value. The lifetime if `_log_data` is unknown. It looks like something which should be passed in as argument like a "context".

Comment: Daniel answered the generic part already - you can of course add your own attributes to a model instance (as long as you don't shadow some name that the ORM needs of course but that's obvious eough). Now whether you should store those exact data on your model instance is another question (there might - or not - be a reason for your feeling that the implementation is "not obvious" or questionnable in any way), but it's impossible to answer  without much more context.

Comment: I can't find the question if this can be done. Did the author of this question ask if this is possible?